# Dynamically add objects to array, fails on one server, not other

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, dynamic

On my local server (running php 5.4.4) this works:

```
$json = array();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {

   $json[] = ['id' => $row['id'] , 'username' => $row['username']];

}
```

On my other server (running php 5.3.28) I get:

```
syntax error, unexpected '['
```

referring to that line

What could be the cause, and how can I fix it? Perhaps an alternative way to dynamically add to an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because short syntax of array is only supported in `PHP 5.4+`

[Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

states that shorter array syntax is available as of `PHP 5.4`. That is why you get the error message since `[` is not supported in **PHP 5.3**

To fix it use regular syntax:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
   $json[] = array('id' => $row['id'] , 'username' => $row['username']);
}
```

As a note, not sure if you are using mysqli or not but it seems to me what you are doing is `->fetchAll` since you are looping through and anyways building an array. In **PDO** there is a function called `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` that will do pretty much same as your loop, you just dont have to loop through it.

Comment: Ah I see. Will try it

Comment: Nice. Now my host just got to update php soon (they are afraid of losing safemode lol) ;) Thanks

Comment: About PDO. Yeah I spend days investigating PDO vs mySQLi. I ended up with mysqli (from regular mysql) and I'm probably gonna stay there, even though PDO has some nice features, and mysqli preparation can be a horrorshow.. but maybe some day

Comment: I think mysql/i also has that option too actually: echo json_encode($conn->query('SELECT id, name FROM thetable')->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$count = 0;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
    $json[$count]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $json[$count]['username'] = $row['username'];
    $count++;
}
```